# "Given Name" when scheduling a consular interview

Tags: usa, visa, uk-citizens, interview

The Department of State Visa Appointment Service web site asks for "Given Name" and pre-populates it with only my first name from when I created an account on the site.

[image: given name input box]

And the tip says "Enter the name as it appears in the passport", however my passports shows "given name**s**" and shows 2 given names.

Do I enter my given first name or both given names?

Answer (score 1):

Enter more than one given name if your passport shows more than one item under "given names".

Later in the process the web puts "Given Name" and "Surname" together and asks you to confirm that this makes up your full name.

Also if you delete the text in the given name box, the web site shows you an example:

[image]

Comment: One source of this confusion is the friction between the US conception that a name has three parts (first, middle, and last, where the last name is the family name, also known as the surname) and the ICAO standard that treats a name as having two parts (a "primary identifier" and a "secondary identifier," where the primary is the family name and the secondary comprises the given names).